# Mongoose find() returning empty Array of SchemaType

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema type called Orders. I am using **Arrays of SchemaTypes** in some properties. When I save it to the database, it's saving everything fine. I can open the database and see all the data there.

But the problem happens in one property called "files", whenever I try to use `find()` or `findOne()` or `findById()`, this property always comes empty, even if I have data to show.

This is my Schemas:

```
const statusChildSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  ...
});

const shippingChildSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  ...
});

const fileChildSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  path: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  type: { type: String, required: true },
});

const ordersSchema = new Mongoose.Schema(
  {
    // Relationships
    creator: {
      type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      required: true,
      ref: 'Users',
      autopopulate: false,
    },
    template: {
      type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Templates',
    },

    // Common
    status: { type: String, trim: true, default: 'new', required: true },
   

    // Child schemas
    status_updates: [statusChildSchema],
    shipping: [shippingChildSchema],
    files: [fileChildSchema],

    // Date properties
    timings: {
      created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
      ...
    },
  },
  { collection: 'Orders', toJSON: { virtuals: true } }
);
```

Both `statusChildSchema` and `shippingChildSchema` is working normally. The problem is only with `fileChildSchema`. They are very similar, so I don't know what to do. I have researched in [Mongoose documents](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) and nothing helpful have been found.

This is the part of my code:

```
 const order = await OrdersModel.findOne({
        _id: orderId,
        creator: userId,
      });

 console.log(order.files); // always printing "[]" empty array
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing last version of Mongoose (Version 5.11.8) and restarting everything. Looks like a bug.